# Catch the exception of an action executed by a task (Task.Delay())

Tags: c#, .net

I built a kind of scheduled task that will execute an action on a scheduled date. I used the `Task.Delay(delay).ContinueWith(action.Invoke())`

Sometimes the action throws an exception, but still cannot propagate this exception to register it properly.

In my example a created a list with three texts and the null text will throw an exception, however I no able to catch this exception in my try..catch block.

```
class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            var texts = new List<string>() { "text 1", null, "text 2"};
            foreach (var text in texts)
            {
                var scheduleDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(10);
                try
                {
                    ReminderControl.AddReminder(Print, text, scheduleDate);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error to schedule the text {text} to be print on {scheduleDate:s}. ex: {ex.Message}");
                }                
            }

            while (true)
            {
                await Task.Delay(2000);
                Console.WriteLine("Doing other things...");
            }
        }

        static void Print(object text)
        {
            if (text is null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(); \\thrown , but not propagated out

            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
    }

    public class ReminderControl
    {
        public static void AddReminder(Action<object> remiderCallback, object context, DateTime scheduleDate)
        {
            var delay = scheduleDate.Subtract(DateTime.UtcNow);
            Task.Delay(delay)
              .ContinueWith(t => remiderCallback.Invoke(context));
            //.ContinueWith(t => throw t.Exception, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted); even with this line the exception still does not propagate
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE using await in the Task.Delay**

```
await ReminderControl.AddReminder(Print, text, scheduleDate);

public static async Task AddReminder(Action<object> remiderCallback, object context, DateTime scheduleDate)
{
    var delay = scheduleDate.Subtract(DateTime.UtcNow);
    await Task.Delay(delay);
    remiderCallback.Invoke(context);
}
```

After that, the `try..catch` block caught the exception, however, the `"Doing other things..."` stopped to be print, probably waiting for the `AddRemind` to finish.

I would like to keep the `"Doing other things..."` being printed asynchronously.

Comment: Using your second approach, you could collect all the tasks returned by `AddReminder` and then wait for them all to complete using `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)`.

Comment: Is it possible for you to put your try catch block inside of your `AddReminder` method and handle things there using await, but at the higher level not using await so your do other things can continue how you want?

Comment: Yes. It is possible, but when the AddReminder action throws an exception, it still needs to be propagated out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want exceptions to bubble up correctly out of tasks, you need to use the full `async` compiler construct. Replace your expression with:

```
await Task.Delay(delay);
action.Invoke();
```

Put it in an `async` function that returns some kind of `Task`, and make sure you await the task returned. That await will bubble exceptions you can catch.

Comment: Thanks. After added the await in the Task.Delay and await the AddReminder into the foreach, my "Doing other things..." in the main thread stoped to be print, probably waiting for the AddReminder. Any guess?

Comment: Guess in regards to what, your analysis is correct. If you mean to ask how to make it still be asynchronous, while keeping the `try`..`catch` around it, put the `try`..`catch` block and the awaited `AddReminder` call in a separate `async` function and call that one without awaiting it.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I need to continue working asynchronously outside. The ```AddReminder``` is like "fire and forget", but if there is any problem, log it. About your last suggestion, I'm a little confused about the two ```try..catch```. So I'm trying to implement it. Thank you.

Comment: I failed miserably, I believe I did not understand your solution. Can you update your answer with that or see where I'm wrong? https://dotnetfiddle.net/nyV7C5

Comment: @RafaelPimenta one problem with testing long running async things like this in .NET fiddle is that .NET fiddle won't allow you to run things for too long, and if there is any kind of infinite loop like your `while(true)` it will timeout fairly quickly.

Comment: @RafaelPimenta, try something like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oekZHb. This overall isn't a good solution, a much better solution involves a dependency injected logging service that gets called on unhandled exceptions, but this implementation is more inline with your project.